# updating database using sqlite in android application

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I try to update my database by using this function:

```
public void onFinish() {
    MyActivity.amountOfVibrations= MyActivity.amountOfVibrations + 1;
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(500); //0.5 seconds of vibration
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    db.updateUser( "sampleMail", "132" );
}
```

The updateUser is as follows:

```
public void updateUser(String email, String total_usage) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ TABLE_LOGIN + " SET "+ KEY_TOTAL_USAGE +" = " + total_usage + " WHERE " + KEY_EMAIL + " = " + email, null);
}
```

The log gives this:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: sampleMail (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE login SET total_usage = 132 WHERE email = sampleMail
```

I already searched for a solution by searching other questions, but I could not find it.

My question is: Why it says no such column sampleMail? I pass `sampleMail` to the `updateUser` function. In the database(phpmyadmin) sampleMail belongs to the column `total_usage` and row `email`.

I dont understand why I get this error. I understand that I have not a column named sampleMail. Hopefully this image will clarify it:

[image: picture showing columns]

Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: try this : "UPDATE login SET total_usage = '132' WHERE email = 'sampleMail' ;"

Comment: always use Logs class to print important strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as the query is looking for a column and not your quoted string.

```java
public void updateUser(String email, String total_usage) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // Create a contentvalues array to store your values that will be updated
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TOTAL_USAGE, total_usage);

    // updating row
    db.update(TABLE_LOGIN, values, KEY_EMAIL + " = '" + email + "'",null);

    db.commit();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: This works for me, but my database is not getting updated. Thanks anyway for your time

Comment: Well, let me know what the error is.  Is the database itself having issues with any updates?  What is the filesystem area where its being stored?  Is it more an issue with the procedure calling this db but not actually having an opportunity to write to it?  Give me details and i'll help where i can.

Comment: I get no errors, that the weird part of it. Even when I hardcode the solution below, it is not geting updated. But Im already using this database for saving registered users

Comment: Try commiting the data.  

`db.commit()`

Comment: Read my editied answer above as there are a few things to try commiting the data.  I changed my query to reflect using the complete update of a record through the execSQL method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the same with hard coded query. If that works, just add apostrophes to the string values.

```
 db.rawQuery("UPDATE login SET total_usage = 132 WHERE email = 'sampleMail';", null);
```

Comment: This works for me too, but my database is not getting updated. Thanks anyway for your time

Comment: You mean, the above query works without any error?  but it does not update your DB ?